# NtQueryDirectoryFile: Access Violation on Windows but not Wine

Tags: windows, winapi, undocumented-behavior, nt

I've looked into using NtQueryDirectoryFile instead of FindFirstFile/FindNextFile to speed up directory iteration.

It's a commonly used tactic in software to use NtQueryDirectoryFile, so I implemented it mostly following how [git did it](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/b69c08c338403a3f8fd2394180664cb9f8164c78/compat/win32/fscache.c#L211) [(my implementation)](https://github.com/1fishe2fishe/EXODUS/blob/5fc7bc6984e901937e139494654cb90c8524e4cc/src/EXODUS/nt/shims.c#L182).

It worked on Wine perfectly and I saw a speedup from 17 to 14 seconds for an operation that iterates through everything (mind you, this takes 2 seconds on Linux so optimization was urgent). However, the problem was that it was failing on Windows, without much explanation on *why*.
It ***always*** faults at the NtQueryDirectoryFile routine, so I know it's a problem with the routine (or my usage of it) and not something else.

Here's the GDB and Visual Studio backtrace(sorry for not being able to post images, it requires reputation): [gdb backtrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tqHj.png), [visual studio backtrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Jp0.png)

As you can see, it's R10 that's the problematic register (set to 0 for some reason), and it's moved from `gs:[0x188]`. From what I can see, this is a [strictly reserved](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/1aff1e6a370ee8c0213a0fd4b220d121da8527aa/include/winternl.h#L363) area of the TEB and I have no way of knowing what it is.

I have tried some fixes like [aligning the buffer to LONGLONG](https://github.com/sandboxie-plus/Sandboxie/commit/8e68dce6ea3e24edfb1b8cd75ad7a1804d7282d5), to no avail.

Is there anyone who can shed some light on this topic? Have I used this incorrectly? I'm completely stuck. I really would ***not*** appreciate answers like using FindFirstFileEx with FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH, which has shown [***not*** to help](https://ariccio.com/2015/01/13/how-fast-are-findfirstfilefindfirstfileex-and-cfilefind-actually/).

Comment: The stack trace makes no sense. ntoskrnl.exe is a kernel-mode component. It shouldn't be running in user mode.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I know it is, but numerous software have shown to link to and run routines from ntoskrnl.exe without any problems, such as [git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/b69c08c338403a3f8fd2394180664cb9f8164c78/compat/win32/fscache.c#L211), which I mostly copied the usage of NtQueryDirectoryFile from, shown in my question. So there must be something wrong with how I used it rather than the superficial fact that I'm calling something Microsoft doesn't want me to. I know you're from Microsoft and wouldn't like me using this, but do you have an idea?

Comment: Git does not link it from ntoskrnl. It links from ntdll.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Raymond Chen, I realized you have to link [NTDLL.DLL](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FFile%2FNtQueryDirectoryFile.html) instead of ntoskrnl.exe to use the userspace version of the routine. (this is an answer to close the question in case others view it)